# How does imputation affect significance test power?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, statistical-power, data-imputation

There are many different imputation methods that make different assumptions about the missingness of the data (MCAR, MNAR, MAR). Since this assumption may not be met, I'm interested in knowing how the power of a significance test on an independent variable in a model built on the imputed data depends on the type of imputation used. It'd be great if you can point to specific sources that also address this question.

Comment: Can you name the imputation methods that interest you?